# How to check if jquery tab with cache enabled has data in cache or not?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I need to mask the tab view with JQuery mask plugin if data is not present in cache for a particular tab. If data is present in cache then no AJAX call will be made and no event is triggered by TAB widget to notify that data has been loaded from cache.

Thanks,
Harvinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the relevant code to check if the tab content has been cached:

```
$.data( ui.tab[ 0 ], "cache.tabs" )
```

`ui.tab[ 0 ]` is the DOM node of the tab's link.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RQXUL/